# How to get all objects based on date in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 simple models in my application:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Order (models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(blank=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True )
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I have many orders with the same date, like this:

```
1. 2017-11-09 | Apples  | 5$
2. 2017-11-09 | Bananas | 2$
3. 2017-11-09 | Pears   | 3$
```

As you can see, there is actually one order (based on the date) with 3 different products. 
How can I get that single order with all of its products and prices? 
So the end result would be something like this:

```
2017-11-09 | Apples  | 5$
           | Bananas | 2$
           | Pears   | 3$
```

I'm using sqllite3

Comment: where do you whant to print your result?

Comment: thanks for the response. 
I actually want that info into a pdf file, but for the start I think a single html file is okay also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the django template you can try it:

```
<table>
    {% for order in orders %}
        {% for item in order.orderitem_set.all %}
        <tr>
            <td>{% if forloop.first %}{{ order.date }}{% endif %}</td>
            <td>{{ item.product.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

in views function add:

```
return render (request, 'index.html', context={'orders': Order.objects.all()})
```

Comment: hmm.. this doesn't seem to work. nothing will be displayed. what i might be missing?

Comment: of course you should add the `orders`  to the context

Comment: what do you mean add the `orders` to the context?

Comment: how do you render the template?

Comment: not sure if i understood your question, but I just call the 
`return render (request, 'index.html')`

Comment: It works! 
Since there is QuerySet, there will be no item.product.name but i will figure it out :)

Comment: glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You must watch template template tags {% regroup %}